# Filter text box in the Users page is expanding vertically after typing

Tags: bug, design

Looks like the filter text box in the [Users page](https://stackoverflow.com/users) is expanding vertically after typing:

[image: User search box expanding vertically]

I've reproduced it in both Chrome and Safari (haven't tried in other browsers though).

Comment: That's due to the ajax spinner. The parent element is a flexbox.

Comment: Cross site duplicate : [Alignment issue in users page while searching user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323543/312043)

Answer (score -2):

You can fix the height of input box.

.s-input.s-input__search{
  height:36px;
}